# Implement strategy pattern service layer using spring data JPA

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, spring-data-jpa, strategy-pattern

We have a following db structure for a lot of modules in db.

db table A is the main table and there are multiple extensions of this table (B, C, D etc) with no primary key of their own but refer primary key of A. We have used JPA @Inheritence joined table approach to manage these. So a parent entity for A and child entities extending A.

We also created multiple jpa repositories for all implementing entities.

When user sends a request, based on certain fields in the request, we have to identify the correct implementation and do CRUD operations on that particular repo.

In order to make it generic and dynamic I created a strategy factory that accepts user input identifies the correct implementation and returns the specific strategy wrapping the specific repo.

The problem is that I have to do this on every call to service class method to identify the correct strategy. I feel there are flaws in this design. Can you suggest a better design ?

Comment: Another way is to make these repos implement an interface and autowire a list of all specific repos. What could be a better way to fetch correct repo from the list based on certain condition?

Comment: Your design sounds sensible to me. A feature of the strategy pattern is that (unlike inheritance) it can change at runtime. That's what you're taking advantage of. What flaws do you feel are there?

Comment: I want the service layer to be stateless to avoid concurrency problems. The downside is that on every call to the service method, I will have to first identify the strategy and then perform the action on it. Should I put in place an interceptor before service so that the strategy is predetermined?

Comment: In a nutshell, I am looking for a cleaner way to implement what I mentioned above.